# What s the use of count in stored proc?

Tags: sql

ex:

```
SELECT @records = COUNT(FS.FILESET_ID) FROM FILE_SET FS WHERE (FILESET_NAME = @FILESET_NAME)
```

thank you

Comment: -1 Please try searching before you ask. https://www.google.com/search?q=SQL COUNT (Also, disregard any w3schools results: http://w3fools.com/ )

Answer (score 1):

[`COUNT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx) is SQL - it is an aggregate function that returns the number of rows in the result set.

In this specific case, it returns the number of records that have the passed in fileset_name.

Answer (score 0):

counting the occurences of fileName in the table, the file name that you will pass as a parameter.

eg if `@FILESET_NAME = 'abc'` then it will count the number of files that have same `file name`.

Now why procedure is counting, only business logic will tell that.